React Native TVOS: force focus on any element after render
Is it possible to force focus on any element? I know I can do it using hasTVPreferredFocus prop, but it works only for the first time - while component is rendered. Is it possible to do something like that but without rerender? For example we are setting setTimeout and after 5 seconds focus switch programmatically from one element to another?
I've tried using hasTVPreferredFocus and rerender component but it has impact on performance.
